# django: join two tables without foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have two models which I want to join but they don't have any foreignkey

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_id                      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quotation_id                    = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    client_id                       = models.ForeignKey(tbl_customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice_number                  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quotation_number                = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date                            = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_amount                    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    total_tax                       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    document_type                   = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

and

```
class Invoice_Description(models.Model):
    invoice_id                      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    client_id                       = models.ForeignKey(tbl_customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quotation_id                    = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    item_id                         = models.ForeignKey(tbl_item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_qty                        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    item_unit_price                 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

`Invoice` contains information about the invoice document, its total price, date, etc while `Invoice_Description` keeps the records of items added on that particular invoice, item price, total quantity, discount on each item, etc.

I want to display all the records in reports with respect to items like

```
ITEM NAME   CUSTOMER NAME   INV. NO.    QTY    DOCUMENT TYPE    UNIT PRICE    SALE PRICE
Item1            Client1                 01                        950.00        1000.00
```

I have all the columns available from `Invoice_Description` except for the `INV. NO.` and `DOCUMENT TYPE` which are in the `Invoice` model.

I don't want to use a ForeignKey in this case because these models are already in use in many places, changing the database will require changes everywhere.

my problem is just that I want to join two models in Django but without ForeignKey so that I may get Invoice No. and Document Type of the corresponding row.

Any ideas on how can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is retrieve an `InvoiceDescription` object that belongs to a given `Invoice`, you could do the following:

```
invoice = Invoice.objects.first()
try:
    description = InvoiceDescription.objects.get(invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id)
except InvoiceDescription.DoesNotExist:
    description = None
```

I am assuming that the field `invoice_id` refers to the invoice ID. Although you didn't declare it using `models.ForeignKey`, it still *acts* as a foreign key in this situation. You just have to do the lookup manually.

Comment: it will be two database hits for one query!?!... btw I solved this issue by declaring a `Foreignkey` in `Invoice_Description` I wanted to join the tables and `models.Foreignkey` is most convenient in doing that in Django... :D